# Wpf user control: makes complex properties editable

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

Suppose you create a standard UserControl or a CustomControl in wpf and then declare a property of a complex type

public ComplexPropertyType AProperty { get; set; }

Complex type is a simple class with a bunch of properties

```
public class ComplexPropertyType 
{
    public int IntP { get; set; }

    public String Strp { get; set; }
}
```

At design time AProperty is not editable.

[image: As you can see the AProperty property is not editable]

I remember that there are attributes from System.ComponentModel that permits me to specify to use a standard property editor to make that property editable, but I cannot remember.

Anyone has a solution that clearly does not require writing a custom property editor? After all If I declare in my control a property that is a collection of complex type Es.

public ObservableCollection ACollOfProperty { get; set; }

Automatically the designer use the System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor that is capable of editing my complex type

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wpf you can use this http://wpg.codeplex.com/ or  use this  [winform contro](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/HostingaWindowsFormsPropertyGridinWPF.htm)

Comment: I wish to use the editor contained in visual studio :), since it works for collection editor, it should be usable for single object

Comment: Your answer is good, but I do not want to create another property editor, since WPF designer has its own, After sleeping one night, with clear mind I was able to remember :) the exact attribute, it was

  [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the attribute myself, is the TypeConverter. You should declare the property in user control with TypeConverterAttribute specifying the ExpandableObjectconverter

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public ComplexPropertyType AProperty { get; set; }
```

Now you should see in the designer a nice NEW button that permits you to populate the value at design time

[image: Now property is designable]

Pressing new it will create an instance of the ComplexPropertyType, so it is editable directly from the designer.

[image: Complex type editing in VS]

Alk.