# How to set UserControl's Custom Property, which is a class, from Properties Window

Tags: c#, properties, user-controls, custom-controls

I have created a UserControl which extends PictureBox Control

```
public partial class AudioMonitor : PictureBox
{
    private SelectionSettings _selectionSettings;

    [Description("Various settings regarding to the selection visuals"), Category("Custom")]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public SelectionSettings SelectionSettings
    {
        get { return this._selectionSettings; }
        set { this._selectionSettings = value; }
    }
}
```

SelectionSettings property is a custom class which I have created as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class SelectionSettings
{
    private SelectionMarker _startMarker;
    private SelectionMarker _endMarker;
    private SelectionPen _selectionStyle;

    public SelectionMarker StartMarker
    {
        get { return this._startMarker; }
        set { this._startMarker = value; }
    }
    public SelectionMarker EndMarker
    {
        get { return this._endMarker; }
        set { this._endMarker = value; }
    }
    public SelectionPen SelectionStyle
    {
        get { return this._selectionStyle; }
        set { this._selectionStyle = value; }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SelectionMarker
{
    private Color _color = Color.White;
    private DashStyle _style = DashStyle.Solid;
    private float _width = 1.0F;

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return this._color; }
        set { this._color = value; }
    }
    public DashStyle Style
    {
        get { return this._style; }
        set { this._style = value; }
    }
    public float Width
    {
        get { return this._width; }
        set { this._width = value; }
    }
    public Pen Pen
    {
        get
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(this._color);
            pen.DashStyle = this._style;
            pen.Width = this._width;

            return pen;
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SelectionPen
{
    private Color _color = Color.White;
    private DashStyle _style = DashStyle.Solid;
    private float _width = 1.0F;
    private float _alpha = 100;

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return this._color; }
        set { this._color = value; }
    }
    public DashStyle Style
    {
        get { return this._style; }
    }
    public float Width
    {
        get { return this._width; }
    }
    public float Alpha
    {
        get { return this._alpha; }
    }
    public int AlphaPercent
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Round(this._alpha * 100 / 255); }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value <= 100)
                this._alpha = (value * 255 / 100);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Alpha percentage should be between (0, 100]");
        }
    }
    public Pen Pen
    {
        get
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb((byte)this._alpha, this._color.R, this._color.G, this._color.B));
            pen.DashStyle = this._style;
            pen.Width = this._width;

            return pen;
        }
    }
}
```

When I place my custom control on a Form and open the Properties Window I can see it as follows : 
[image]

As you can see I can not set "SelectionSettings" property from the "Properties" window at the design time. What I need is to place the "..." button next to the Property name and open a pop-up to set values.

It should look something like this : 
[image]

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: I'm trying to find the reference now as I had a similar problem last year. Essentially your class has to serialize / reserialize to a string. As you can see for font it lists both the selected font name and the size with a ; delimiter. Will post an example as soon as I find it.

Comment: Your SelectionSettings needs to have a type converter, without this the property will be displayed as greyed out. The converter needs to inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter. You can see this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx and scroll down to Displaying Complex Properties section.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But as far as I can understand this document explains how to create a PropertyGrid to change values at the run-time. But I want to insert this functionality at the design time at the Properties Windows. I just had a quick gaze on the document and might possibly miss something, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Back to the drawing board! Will see what I can come up with :)

Comment: From what I can see it uses the same TypeConverter pattern for the VS design time Properties window. See this question's 2nd answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016992/wpf-user-control-makes-complex-properties-editable

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add an [Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to `AudioMonitor`'s `SelectionSettings` property.

To do this, you should create a custom class derived from the [UITypeEditor Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor(v=vs.110).aspx).

In order to inherit from `UITypeEditor`, your project must reference `System.Design`, which can be done by going to the Project menu, selecting Add Reference to bring up the Reference Manager, navigating to Assemblies->Framework on the left panel and making sure `System.Design` is checked in the list.

In your custom `UITypeEditor` derived class, override the method `EditValue` to bring up a custom dialog that edits a value of type `SelectionSettings`. Then set the Editor Attribute on your `SelectionSettings` property to your custom `UITypeEditor` derived class.

Here's a generic code example of how this would look:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// ...

[Editor(typeof(SomeProperty_Editor), typeof(UITypeEditor))] // You might be able to place this attribute on class SomeType, but I haven't tried yet
public SomeType SomeProperty
{
    get { /* stuff */ }
    set { /* stuff */ } // optional, really
}

class SomeProperty_Editor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)(provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)));
        SomeProperty_EditorWindow EditorWindow = new SomeProperty_EditorWindow(value as SomeType);
        service.ShowDialog(EditorWindow);
        if (EditorWindow.EditCancelled)
            return value;
        else
            return EditorWindow.GetEdittedValue();
    }
}

class SomeProperty_EditorWindow : Form
{
    public SomeProperty_EditorWindow(SomeType CurrentProperty) : base()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        // Grab info in CurrentProperty here and display it on form
    }

    public void InitializeComponents()
    {
        // write yourself or use designer
    }

    public SomeType GetEdittedValue()
    {
        // return editted value from form components 
    }

    public bool EditCancelled = false; // Set true if cancel button hit
}
```

You may want to look up the `PropertyGrid` Control as it could be very useful in your EditorWindow. Also, you can go to the `UITypeEditor` Class's MSDN page, look at all of the .NET derived classes under "Inheritance Hierarchy" to see if there is a built in editor that is close in functionality to what you want to do and inherit directly from that class.